# Несколько моделей для 1 контроллера и представления

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Пишу на asp.net mvc.

В одном view должна быть целая куча записываемых и показываемых данных, по-этому мне было бы очень удобно разделить модель на много маленьких моделей по категориям, что бы было легче ориентироваться их полях.

Однако так как это надо сделать все в одном view, которое может иметь только одну модель, такой способ не прокатит.

Как можно это реализовать иначе?

Comment: В таких случаях (сложное представление состоит из множества блоков) обычно во вьюхе делают partial view с отдельными маленькими модельками, вы не об этом? И, вы зря выделяете внутристрочным форматированием слова asp.net и view в тексте вопроса -- это [излишнее форматирование](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1328/213987).

Comment: @AK, подходит идеально, спасибо большое

Comment: Еще встречал подобные [реализации](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/multiple-models-in-single-view-in-mvc/), причем чаще всего встречались реализации с помощью кортежей.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В таких случаях (сложное представление состоит из множества блоков) обычно во вьюхе делают partial view с отдельными маленькими модельками.

Answer (score 0):

Как было сказано выше, разбейте view на несколько partial views. Что касается передачи данных с сервера в эти частичные представления (partial views), то можно создать несколько классов (по одному для каждого частичного представления, ну или в зависимости от необходимости/целесообразности/предпочтений и т.д.). Создайте модель для главного представления (большой view), которая будет содержать типы созданных вами ранее моделей для частичных представлений. И на вьюхе передавайте эти модели (свойства основной большой view model) в соотвествующие частичные представления.